# Heatmap for nonuniformly spaced data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, heatmap

I want to create a heatmap using matplotlib like the one depicted below. The data is not uniformly spaced as you can see from the axes ticks. 
So suppose we have

```
x = [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 5, 7]
y = [.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5]
vals = np.random.rand(len(x), len(y))
```

How is such an interpolated plot created in matplotlib?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should interpolate missing data, I used in one of my project following:

```
#create regular grid
xi, yi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100), np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 100)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

#interpolate missing data
rbf = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(x, y, z, function='linear')
zi = rbf(xi, yi)
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly more expanded version of askorek's answer:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
import scipy

def nonuniform_imshow(x, y, z, aspect=1, cmap=plt.cm.rainbow):
  # Create regular grid
  xi, yi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100), np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 100)
  xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

  # Interpolate missing data
  rbf = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(x, y, z, function='linear')
  zi = rbf(xi, yi)

  _, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))

  hm = ax.imshow(zi, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap,
                 extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.max(), y.min()]) 
  ax.scatter(x, y)
  ax.set_aspect(aspect)
  return hm

heatmap = nonuniform_imshow(x, y, z)
plt.colorbar(heatmap)
plt.show()
```

[image]